# Parsing PDF files using Python

Tags: javascript, python, pdf, pdf.js

(1) Is there a way to search for texts in a pdf file and go to that location in the pdf file using Python?
(2) Is there a way to highlight a text in a pdf file and that text get extracted, using Python?

I tried using Javascript pdf.js, which actually worked but I want to try Python. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For searching for text within a PDF file you can use [PyMuPDF](http://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [pdfminer](https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six). PyMuPDF would also let you create a PDF viewer and highlight the text if that's what you have in mind.